# dissertation cover photo

Tags: thesis

I am going to submit my doctoral thesis, one of the optional things we can do in our university is having a photo of author on the back cover of hard copy of thesis. I have no idea for that. How do you think about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be funny to look at it in 30 years from now ;-) - go for it!

Nobody except from close friends / family members will ever see it...

Comment: And thesis reviewers / advisors, though.

Answer (score 4):

It is very likely that nobody except you and the people you will give your thesis to will ever see the hard copy of your thesis. (And some random people looking at some theses in the library - however, if this is not uncommon in your university, they will not judge you negatively for having a picture.)

So, you should consider:

- Do you think it's nice to have a photo of you on your thesis? Many people like to have a nice thesis on their shelf which has not only good context, but nice formatting, nice colours, nice pictures etc. Some people see a thesis as a pure formality and are happy to do as little "style" things as possible. In which class do you fall? And if you care, do you think the thesis looks better or worse with your picture?
- Will the people you give the thesis to appreciate it? (Don't forget to consider parents and grandparents!)
- How much more does it cost? Do you feel it is worth the price?
- Is there a place at university you really like (e.g. a certain place in the library, your office, the mensa etc.) and you would really miss it after your studies? It can be nice to have a picture of yourself in that place on the thesis (if this is allowed).